# 2002 Chevy Malibu spark plugs

Tags: engine

Three of the spark plugs in my 2002 Chevy Malibu are easy to reach and change, which I did successfully. The other three spark plugs are difficult to reach, difficult to see, and are in a position where I cannot get them started turning without banging the socket wrench on the car firewall. What are the best things to do to change the three difficult-to-reach spark plugs?

Thank you.

HBL

Comment: A photo might help get better answers.

Comment: The real answer, unfortunately, is "don't buy a car with a transverse V engine if you want to be able to do your own maintenance."

Answer (score 1):

Off-hand, my best suggestion would be to try different types and lengths of socket extensions, including (my favorite for situations like this) one with a universal joint in it. You could also try using a regular non-socket wrench on the end of the spark plug socket, if you can reach it.